# Display posts in descending order of total_votes of polls plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I have added plugin wp-polls for polls. It is showing total votes columns in plugin page but i want to display posts on home page in descending order of total votes but post does not have any relationship with polls tables. So how can i display that, if any solution please tell me!

Comment: Looks like the poll answers are stored directly to SQL...it will require quite a bit of work to get this going...I think that one possibility would be to create a custom field for the poll's total count for each post, create a custom script that will populate the custom fields by obtaining the relevant values from the sql tables, and then you would be able to use 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num' as an argument in your query to order the results based on the custom field value

Comment: Hey zoranc first of all thanks for reply.wp-polls create custom tables which does not have any relation with other wp-tables. now if u say i m creating total_votes custom field then how can i fetch that value from wp-polls tables related to that polls belong to the post.